# Отдела или отделом

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, согласование

Назначить на должность руководителя сектором/сектора ХХХ

Назначить на должность руководителя отделом/отдела ЧЧЧ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: Назначить на должность **руководителя сектора, отдела.**

[**Словарь-справочник Розенталя "Управление в русском языке"**](http://padaread.com/?book=49773&pg=296)

Руководить (чем?) отделом ― руководитель (чего?) отдела,  но руководитель полетом космического корабля (лицо, направляющее чьи -либо **действия**).

Также **для причастий**: заведовать отделом ― заведующий отделом, командовать фронтом ― командующий фронтом (творительный падеж сохраняется).